# How to make the popup as a child of the button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to position a jQuery UI Dialog popup under  button.

I could change the position to left and right but the popup is coming on top of the screen.

How can I set popup position height?

Here is my code:

**js**

```
      $(function () {
          $("#myDialog").dialog({
               autoOpen: false,

               show: 'fade',
               hide: 'fade',
               modal: false,
               width: 300,
               draggable: false,
               minHeight: 200,
               //buttons: {
               //    "Close": function () {
               //        $(this).dialog("close");
               //    }
               //}
          });

          $("#myLink").click(function (e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               $("#myDialog").dialog("open");
               return false;
          });

          function positionDialog() {
               linkOffset = $("#myLink").position();
               linkWidth = $("#myLink").width();
               linkHeight = $("#myLink").height();
               scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();
               $("#myDialog").dialog("option", "position", [(linkOffset.left - 550/ 2) + linkWidth / 2, (linkOffset.top - 220 / 2 ) + linkHeight - scrolltop]);
           }

           positionDialog();

           $(window).resize(function () {
               positionDialog();
           });

           $(window).scroll(function () {
               positionDialog();
           });
      });
```

**html**

```
<div style="text-align:center; float:left"><a href="#" id="myLink">Login here</a></div>
         <div id="myDialog" title=" Login">
         @Html.Partial("_LoginPopupPartial")                 
</div>
```

Can someone please help me. The popup should come where ever I place my button. and also it should come below the button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set popup position with respect to button element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035956/how-to-set-popup-position-with-respect-to-button-element)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery UI position utility to achieve what you need in a much simpler manner. Reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

Instead of doing all your own calculations for offset and position, when opening the dialog, simply do this:

```
$('#myDialog').dialog('option', 'position', { my: "top", at: "center bottom", of: this }).dialog("open");
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/W7ayC/

The .position() utility makes it easy to place the resulting dialog wherever you want relative to the window, the object that triggered the opening or any other element via standard jQ selector.

Hope this helps!